# How to get repel to add only a single label in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to get only a single label added onto my `ggplot` using `geom_text_repel`, however, it gives this output:
[image]

I want it so that only the point circled in red remains.

Here is the code I'm working with:

```
p <- ggplot(three_rain, aes(Year)) + 
geom_line(aes(y=Rainfall), color = "#00AFBB") + 
geom_line(aes(y=mean(Rainfall))) +   
geom_text_repel(x=three_rain$Year[which.max(three_rain$Rainfall)],y = max(three_rain$Rainfall), label = "Max Rainfall")+   
annotate(geom = "point", x = 2020, y = 287.6, colour = "orange", size = 2)+  
geom_text_repel(y = three_rain$Rainfall, label = three_rain$Rainfall, size = 2.5,  arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.02, "npc"))) +   
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5)) +   
scale_x_continuous("Year", labels = as.character(Year), breaks = Year)
```

I have used `geom_text` however it overlaps with the orange point even though its only a single label. I'd prefer to have it work with `geom_text_repel` for the arrow.

An example of reproducible code:

```
structure(list(Year = 1991:2020, Rainfall = c(94.5, 96.4, 21.1, 
90.7, 176.7, 112.5, 213.7, 61.2, 88.3, 152, 117.3, 241.9, 56.1, 
102.2, 75, 76.4, 98.5, 80.2, 27.4, 56.9, 154.7, 69, 64.3, 188.2, 
77.7, 142.4, 111.8, 78, 83, 287.6)), row.names = c(NA, -30L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Filter out the `data` passed to the relevant `geom_text_repel`:

```r
ggplot(three_rain, aes(Year, Rainfall)) + 
  geom_line( color = "#00AFBB") + 
  geom_line(aes(y=mean(Rainfall))) +   
  geom_text_repel(data = three_rain[which.max(three_rain$Rainfall),],
                  aes(label = "Max Rainfall")) +   
  annotate(geom = "point", x = 2020, y = 287.6, colour = "orange", size = 2)+  
  geom_text_repel(aes(label = Rainfall), 
                  size = 2.5,  arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.02, "npc"))) +   
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5)) +   
  scale_x_continuous("Year", breaks = unique(three_rain$Year))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can pass to repel only the data for the row you need:

```
p <- ggplot(three_rain, aes(Year)) + 
    geom_line(aes(y=Rainfall), color = "#00AFBB") + 
    geom_line(aes(y=mean(Rainfall))) +   
    geom_text_repel(data=three_rain[which.max(three_rain$Rainfall),],x=three_rain$Year[which.max(three_rain$Rainfall)],y = max(three_rain$Rainfall), label = "Max Rainfall")+   
    annotate(geom = "point", x = 2020, y = 287.6, colour = "orange", size = 2)+  
    geom_text_repel(y = three_rain$Rainfall, label = three_rain$Rainfall, size = 2.5,  arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.02, "npc"))) +   
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try:

```
library(ggplot2)
#Data labels
labs <- data.frame(x=three_rain$Year[which.max(three_rain$Rainfall)],
                   y = max(three_rain$Rainfall), label = "Max Rainfall",
                   label = "Max Rainfall",stringsAsFactors = F)
#Plot
ggplot(three_rain, aes(Year)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y=Rainfall), color = "#00AFBB") + 
  geom_line(aes(y=mean(Rainfall))) +   
  geom_text_repel(data=labs,aes(x=x,y=y,label=label))+   
  annotate(geom = "point", x = 2020, y = 287.6, colour = "orange", size = 2)+  
  geom_text_repel(y = three_rain$Rainfall, label = three_rain$Rainfall, size = 2.5,  arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.02, "npc"))) +   
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5))
```

Output:

[image]